# How does a static charge produce field around it?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

How and why does a static charge produce an electric field around it? What makes it to induce electric field around a positive or negative charge?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "why" but not "how" answer, and a "how" but not "why" answer that you might be considering, so as to exclude it, or approve of it? Surely, you don't want large numbers of interlocutors to play "bring me another How",  with you, no?

Answer (score -2):

Yes of course.

The overall charge of the universe must balance. So if you have a metal sphere that is negatively charged there must some positive charges floating around somewhere in the universe. Thus there would be an electric field between your sphere and the positive charges - wherever they are.

Comment: I am aware of no definitive reason why the universe has to have a balanced charge.  That's a conjecture, not a certainty.  But by the same logic anti-matter and matter should balance, but that doesn't appear to be the case, so we cannot take "balancing the books" for granted.

Comment: This said, charge is conserved, and the maximum charge imbalance in the overall universe which is consistent with observation is very low. So, while the reasoning isn't entirely sound, the conjecture is probably true or very nearly true.

Answer (score -2):

A static charge created an electric field by emitting photons. Nothing is required to induce this to happen.

Comment: A static charge  does emit photons because of the thermic equilibration with the surrounding matter. The electric charge is an intrinsic property of a free electron and the proton too and the resulting electric fields are intrinsic too.